# Ionic 2 Alert Warning

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I get the following warning when I open up an Alert - **ngSwitchWhen is deprecated and will be removed. Use *ngSwitchCase instead**

The issue is that as a result of this warning it seems none of the event listeners are working and I also cannot get the Alert to dismiss programmatically. If anyone could help that would be really awesome! Please find my code below:

```
openAlert() {
let prompt = Alert.create({
    title: 'Test',
    message: "Test",
    inputs: [{
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Name'
    }, ],
    enableBackdropDismiss: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: data => {
            console.log('cancelled');
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Continue',
        handler: data => {
            console.log('continue');
        }
    }]
});
this._navController.present(prompt);
}
```

Here is some additional info

```
Your system information: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.9
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.30
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.16
Node Version: v4.4.5
```

Comment: Could you create a plunker with your code?

Comment: Sorry I really cannot. This code runs using nodejs and the ionic framework. This is just an excerpt you could put in and controller in any ionic 2 project

Comment: `Node` is just used to manage the references and `ionic framework` just like `angular2` at the end is only another `js file` to be imported. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/F4C4COTrX6wWoPVgwLcq?p=preview) you can find a working (and clean) `Ionic beta 9` project to add your code and we can see if we can replicate the issue.

Comment: The ionic team were able to help me out with this. The solution is to change my angular version to "2.0.0-rc.1" where it was originally "^2.0.0-rc.1"

Comment: Hi sebaferraras, I actually a template ionic2 app on plunker and was busy adding my demo when the solution came through from the Ionic team. Thank you for your assistance. I will be using this plunker template in future for sure!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Please update your question with the answer so other users running into the same issue can find the solution quicker.